# Jquery and img gallery with data attributes not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am building an image gallery using HTML5, PHP and JQUERY. The PHP and HTML are fine as far as I can tell. I am trying to get it to when the user clicks the thumbnail it loads into a modal and I would like the img in the modal to change so I do not have to have one generated for each img. I am fresh to JQUERY and have been working on getting this working all day. can someone point out where I am going wrong?

I expect the img to load in the modal. Yet when I test it, the modal opens but it only shows the broken img icon.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('a .thumb').click(function (e) {
        $('#lgImg').attr('src', data-img-url);
    });
</script>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body text-center">
                <img id="lgImg" class="" src="#"/>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<a href='#myModal' data-toggle='modal' data-img-url='/images/prod/img1.jpg' class='thumb'><img class='img-thumbnail thumb' src='/images/prod/img1.jpg' width='20%' height='20%'></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're attempting to manipulate an element inside a Bootstrap modal it's better practice to use the `show.bs.modal` event to insert the image from the corresponding trigger element.

```js
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  var imgUrl = $(e.relatedTarget).data('imgUrl')
  $('#lgImg').attr('src', imgUrl)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body text-center">
                <img id="lgImg" class="img-fluid" />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<a href='#myModal' data-toggle='modal' data-img-url='https://placeimg.com/640/480/any/grayscale' class='thumb'><img class='img-thumbnail thumb' src='https://media.wired.com/photos/5926db217034dc5f91becd6b/master/w_1904,c_limit/so-logo-s.jpg' width='20%' height='20%'></a>
```

Alternatively, to continue using your methodology, you can change your code to reference the data attribute from your anchor:

```
$('a .thumb').click(function (e) {
    $('#lgImg').attr('src', $(this).parent().data('imgUrl'));
});
```

Comment: I am at a complete loss. This is still not working for me. I am a complete novice with jquery, and have no idea where I am going wrong. Here is a link to the actual page. Maybe there is something wrong deeper in the code I am not seeing.http://nerdsforhire.pnd-productions.com/shop.php

Comment: Put the code at the end of your document before `</body>` or wrap your code in `$(function() { /** code here**/ })`

Comment: AWESOME! As I said I am a complete noob with this! I have not worked with design or scripts in well over 14 years. Trying to re-teach an old dog new tricks. Can you explain why this works compared to having the script in the head tag?

Comment: Script in the head tag is executed before the rest of the document is loaded in the DOM. Script at the end of your document is executed after the document content is loaded in the DOM. You should avoid script references in the head and add them to the end of your document where you can.

Comment: Thank you for the education, and assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Your reference to the attribute value of `data-img-url` isn't correct. Check out the `.data()` [jquery method](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-key-value) and try setting up your click handler like this:

```
$('a .thumb').click(function (e) {            
  $('#lgImg').attr('src', $(this).parent().data('img-url'));
});
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it still is not working.

Comment: @Brice that should read `$(this).parent().data('img-url')` as the `.thumb` is a direct descendant of `a`

Comment: I am at a complete loss. This is still not working for me. I am a complete novice with jquery, and have no idea where I am going wrong. Here is a link to the actual page. Maybe there is something wrong deeper in the code I am not seeing.nerdsforhire.pnd-productions.com/shop.php

Answer (score 0):

Note: you may want to style your image or you can see the img inside the modal can be oversized the way you have it right now (assuming you don't have CSS you didn't include)

```js
$('a .thumb').click(function (e) {   
  //You need to reference the clicked thumbnail, then its parent since the a element has the data-img-url you're looking for.
  //An alternative would be to look for the closest a element up the DOM tree using closest.
  //$('#lgImg').attr('src', $(this).closest("a").attr("data-img-url"));  
  $('#lgImg').attr('src', $(this).parent().attr("data-img-url"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body text-center">
                <img id="lgImg" class="" src="#"/>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<a href='#myModal' data-toggle='modal' data-img-url='https://placeimg.com/640/480/any/grayscale.jpg' class='thumb'><img class='img-thumbnail thumb' src='https://placeimg.com/640/480/any/grayscale.jpg' width='20%' height='20%'></a>
```

Comment: I am at a complete loss. This is still not working for me. I am a complete novice with jquery, and have no idea where I am going wrong. Here is a link to the actual page. Maybe there is something wrong deeper in the code I am not seeing.nerdsforhire.pnd-productions.com/shop.php

Comment: Move everything in the <script> tags to the bottom of the page.  Example: Doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/752r1hpm/  Does work: https://jsfiddle.net/53dyxhmf/